# php exception handling without error_reporting on

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm working on a legacy app where towards the beginning of most files, php error reporting is disabled using `error_reporting(0)`. The app is mostly functioning, but if I enable the error reporting there are a lot of errors and execution stops at the first one. When error reporting is disabled, errors are not logged anywhere. If I enable error reporting, error logging works great. Is there any way to enable error reporting without stopping execution of the script, as though error reporting was disabled? I need to log the errors but I also need the app to continue functioning as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The very definition of an error is that the program has encountered a state which it cannot recover from. If it was recoverable/avoidable/non-destructive, then it would probably be a warning.

Exceptions are different, they are catchable and you can decide what to do with them with try/catch. I see a *lot* of code here where people simply ignore any caught exceptions and continue on as if nothing happened, but that is usually a big mistake and the reason they had a problem that warranted an SO post. Most exceptions should be handled by cleaning up your program [complete file writes, close handles/connections/etc] before displaying an error and halting execution.

Some of this may be accomplished with [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) but execution should still be halted at the end of your custom error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is in your php.ini file:

```
display_errors = Off
error_log = /var/log/php/error.log
log_errors = On
```